# How can I get R back

Tags: java, android, delete-file

I just deleted the class R in my Android-Project, how can I get it back. I tried to clean the Project Setup, I created new Files which reference R. But nothing works.
Please help me what can I do?

Best Regards

safari

Comment: I would start by pulling the power cord. :-)

Comment: its a laptop, still power on it haha :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can right click on the project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties. That should cause the R.java class to be re-generated.

Comment: Try to create new project and check if R.java is created, if it is then check if your old project doesn`t have errors in layout folder.

Comment: By the way did you have 9 patch images in your project?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using eclipse then follow below steps

1. Goto Project Menu and then clean
2. Select "Clean projects selected below"
3. Select your project
4. select "start a buid immediatly"
5. Select "build only selected project" and
6. click ok to clean your workspace and build from scratch.

If this will not work then edit any of your java file or try to change Android library file,
you need to anyhow build that will generate R.java

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem and other similar problems related to the build in the past.

The steps to follow are:

- Clean the project.

If this does not solve the problem, clean the project and then restart eclipse. This always resolves the problem for me.